# How to proof $\beta_1 = \frac{(Sy) r}{Sy}$

Tags: least-squares

I can proof uptill $\beta_2 = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(Y_i-\text{mean of} \;y)(X_i-\text{mean of} \;x)}{X_i-\text{mean of} \;x}$

Comment: Please, check that the edits in your post match with your question and try to improve the way you type for the next time. Also, I think you should give more context to your question and include your own work in order to get useful answers.

Comment: Thankyou so much for helping me out in editing

Comment: Denominator is squared term